# iOS adjust UICollectionView Insets after hiding Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, searchbar

[image: Search off]

[image: Search]

```
@IBAction func searchOn() {
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

What I want to do here is to hide navigation bar when presenting Search bar   and place cells in correct position, because now they are going under search bar.

One of the solutions I was able to think of is just to animateWithDuration UIEdgeInsetsMake downwards same distance as they get moved up when navigation bar hides. But the problem is that I don't know the duration of the animation between switching navigation and search bars.

Can anyone help figure this out?

Or at least help me to get the duration of animation which switches between navigation and search bars.

Answer (score 0):

write this code in viewDidLoad() method.

```
let flow: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = CollectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
      flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(70, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: this leads nowhere. Cells are keep getting under search bar anyway

Comment: write above codein last line of  inside searchOn() func.

Answer (score 0):

one more way is to try setting the `contentOffset` to required position.and change the y position to move up and down, u can give negative values also

for example,

```
    //without animation
    collectionview.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100);
    //with animation
    collectionview.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: true)
```

and also u can take advantage of `sectionInset` also as Chirag Patel mentioned

Comment: well I thought this was going to solve my problem, at least the location where cells are now displayed is correct, but even with setContentOffset animated cells are jumping around, instead of staying still.

Comment: ok, u don't need to set it repeatedly, set this as soon as search control is presented and reset back i mean set zero point when dismiss of the search control

Comment: Well that's obvious, but that's not the case. It seems like animation between, navigation bar disappearing and changing offsets is not the same. Navigation moves content faster than offsets are changing, or the other way around. I can't tell. But during this "switching" process, cells do not stay in same place, as they should (that is what I want to achieve). They're are slightly twitching few points up and down until search bar appears.